# Distributed replicated binary storage for large datasets

Tags: database, nosql

We need some existing solution for a very narrow problem: write-once read-many-times timeseries storage.

Properties we care about are:

- low read latency
- replicated
- scalable (ability to add more resources as in physical hw or money)

We tried Google AppEngine datastore with data chunked in ~1M blobs. Unfortunately, read latency and pricing are not that pleasant.

Options we are about to consider are:

- Amazon SimpleDB
- HDFS/HBase on our own hosting
- Some of NoSQL breed (Tokyo Tyrant?)
- BLOBs in MySQL (manual sharding has to be done though)

Are we missing anything? Should we consider other options or prioritize one over another?

Answer (score 3):

Try Lustre and or Ceph. Both have (or will have) commercial support.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at Microsoft's Azure [Storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/tour/storage/) Services. They provide blobs, tables (non-relational) and queues for a reasonable price.